# Resample daily data to hourly dataframe with dateindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing, resampling

I have this dataframe:

```
date,Prices
2018-01-01,  45.338
2018-01-02,  39.955
```

I would like to resample this hourly taking advantage of dateindex. In particular I would like to assign the same value to each hour of the day. In other word,I expect to obtain the following dataframe:

```
date,Prices         
2018-01-01  00:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  01:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  02:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  03:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  04:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  05:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  06:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  07:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  08:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  09:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  10:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  11:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  12:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  13:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  14:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  15:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  16:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  17:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  18:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  19:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  20:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  21:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  22:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-01  23:00:00    ,   45.338
2018-01-02  00:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  01:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  02:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  03:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  04:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  05:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  06:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  07:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  08:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  09:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  10:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  11:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  12:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  13:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  14:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  15:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  16:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  17:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  18:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  19:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  20:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  21:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  22:00:00    ,   39.955
2018-01-02  23:00:00    ,   39.955
```

I read the dataframe as

```
dfr     =  pd.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=True,index_col=0,
                       infer_datetime_format=True,
                       cache_dates=True)
```

After that I try to apply a sort of resample following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522090/resample-daily-data-to-hourly-dataframe-and-copy-contents). However, I would like take advantage of dateindex, so I do the following:

```
 new_df = dfr.index.resample("H").ffill().rename(
     {"Prices"}, axis=1
 )
```

However, I get the following error:

```
   new_df = dfr.index.resample("H").ffill().reset_index().rename(

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'resample'
```

I have also try this:

```
new_dfr = dfr.resample(rule='H')['Prices'].mean()
```

but I get:

```
date
2018-01-01 00:00:00    45.338
2018-01-01 01:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 03:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 04:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 05:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 06:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 07:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 08:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 09:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 10:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 11:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 12:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 13:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 14:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 15:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 16:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 17:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 18:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 19:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 20:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 21:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 22:00:00       NaN
2018-01-01 23:00:00       NaN
2018-01-02 00:00:00    39.955
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) :

```
dfr = pd.read_csv("input.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
​
dt_idx = pd.date_range(dfr.index.min(), dfr.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(hours=23), freq="H")
​
new_df = dfr.reindex(dt_idx).ffill()
```

​
Output :

```
print(new_df)
                     Prices
2018-01-01 00:00:00   45.34
2018-01-01 01:00:00   45.34
2018-01-01 02:00:00   45.34
...                     ...
2018-01-02 21:00:00   39.95
2018-01-02 22:00:00   39.95
2018-01-02 23:00:00   39.95

[48 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, remove `.index` for processing DataFrame instead `df.index` in [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
 new_df = dfr.resample("H").ffill()
```

But there is problem with last hours, possible solution with append helper DataFrame with add `23H`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dfr.iloc[-1].tolist(), 
                  index=[dfr.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(hour=23)],
                  columns=dfr.columns)
print (df)
                     Prices
2018-01-02 23:00:00  39.955

new_df = pd.concat([dfr, df]).resample("H").ffill()
```

---

```
print (new_df)
   Prices
2018-01-01 00:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 01:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 02:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 03:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 04:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 05:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 06:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 07:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 08:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 09:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 10:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 11:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 12:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 13:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 14:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 15:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 16:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 17:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 18:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 19:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 20:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 21:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 22:00:00  45.338
2018-01-01 23:00:00  45.338
2018-01-02 00:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 01:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 02:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 03:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 04:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 05:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 06:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 07:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 08:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 09:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 10:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 11:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 12:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 13:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 14:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 15:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 16:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 17:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 18:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 19:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 20:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 21:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 22:00:00  39.955
2018-01-02 23:00:00  39.955
```